# Django: Using signals with inline models

Tags: python, django

Using Django 2.2

I have two models, `Job` and `Operation`, where `Operation` has a foreign key relation to `Job` (ie, a job can have 0 or more operations).

I want people to enter info about jobs and operations together via the Django Admin interface, using [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin). (This means that on the Admin site, on the job create/edit page, a user can add one or more operations "inline" without leaving the page.)

`Job` has a few fields computed from its related operations. Rather than simply make them computed `@property` properties, I want them to be regular database fields that get updated when the operations change via signals. It looks something like this:

```py
class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharFields(...)

    def compute_fields(self):
        qs = self.operations.filter(...)  # get data from operations
        self.name = ...  # set properties using that data
        self.save()
    ...


class Operation(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name="operations", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...


@receiver(post_save, sender=Operation)
def update_job_on_operation_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Update job fields when an operation is saved"""
    instance.job.compute_fields()
```

**Here is the issue:** If someone is editing the `Job` form on the Django Admin, and they add multiple operations inline before hitting save, then the receiver function gets called multiple times simultaneously. I am a little worried about a race condition, as well as the inefficiency of each signal leading `Job` to recompute some properties and save to the database.

It would be better, perhaps, to attach the receiver to `Job`, so the function only gets called once, but if someone were to edit an `Operation` outside of the `Job` form that should also trigger a recompute.

Is it possible to set up similar `post_save` receivers for both `Job` and `Operation` and say "ignore the operation receiver if the operation was edited inline as part of the job form"? Are there alternative solutions?